# Application of Brianchon's theorem problem

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, conic-sections, tangent-line, geometric-construction

**The lines $a$, $b$ and $c$ are given, point $A_1$ on line $a$ and point $B_1$ on line $b$. Conic $\mathcal{C}$ passes through points $A_1$ and $B_1$, and lines $a$, $b$ and $c$ are its tangents. Construct  tangent $d$ of the conic which is parallel to $c$ (and different from $c$). In which cases there is no solution?**

I applied Brianchon's theorem to the "hexagon" $aabbcc$ in order to find touching point $C_1$ of tangent $c$ and  conic $\mathcal{C}$. However I don't know what to do next. How do I proceed from this?

[image]

Comment: Two tangents are parallel only if their tangency points are the endpoints of a diameter.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca In that case I would only know how to proceed if the given conic was a circle. I would just find the circumscribed circle of $A_1B_1C_1$ and draw a line through its center and point $C_1$ and then draw a line passing through their point of intersection that is also parallel to $c$. But I wouldn't know what to do if the given conic was anything other than a circle? Either way, I really appreciate you sharing this useful fact with me, it's really helpful. Thanks!!

Comment: It's easy to find the center for an ellipse or hyperbola. Draw the line through $P$ and the midpoint of $A_1B_1$, then the line through $M$ and the midpoint of $C_1B_1$.  The intersection of those lines is the center.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Gee, it works!I just went to Geogebra to see if everything works for hyperbola following the instructions you gave me. What can I say.....Amazing